# Query triggered on delete of a row from a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am using the following query to find out the row which has been updated/ inserted from the table PER_PREVIOUS_EMPLOYERS. Now i want a query to be triggered when any row is deleted from the table PER_PREVIOUS_EMPLOYERS. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
papf.full_name,
papf.email_address
FROM PER_PREVIOUS_EMPLOYERS PPEV,
per_all_people_F papf
WHERE PPEV.ROWID = :ROWID
and PPEV.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID= 81
and papf.person_ID=ppev.person_id
and trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
```

I am using this in oracle Alert so i cannot use the create or replace on delete trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER DELETE
   ON PER_PREVIOUS_EMPLOYERS
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   name varchar2;
   email varchar2;

BEGIN
   SELECT 
   papf.full_name,
   papf.email_address
   INTO name, email
   FROM PER_PREVIOUS_EMPLOYERS PPEV,
   per_all_people_F papf
   WHERE PPEV.ROWID = :ROWID
   and PPEV.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID= 81
   and papf.person_ID=ppev.person_id
   and trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date;

   --store the result somewhere
EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

Comment: i cannot use create or replace trigger as i am using oracle alert. i can only use a pl/sql query

Comment: Take a look at Oracle Alert events, looks like it may help.

Comment: Nope in the guide only "after insert" n "after update" is given. What i need is after delete

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all data in a table like all_data in the morning , and end of day you can insert all data in a table like all_data_end_day 
by comparison of all_data and all_data_end_morning you can find out which rows are deleted ,
all of rows exist in all_data and are not  exist in all_data_end_day